# How can I change custom cells label parameters in viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, uitableview, parameters, uilabel, custom-cell

I have custom cell called `MyCustomCell`, there is a label named `pushLabel`, in table view I get parameters of label like this:

```
cell.pushLabel.text = @"text";
```

I need to get in that label parameters in `viewDidLoad` (where table view is located), how this can be done?

Comment: In viewDidLoad method, UITableView still have not been loaded. Make your requirement clear

Comment: I need to set this label hidden in viewDidLoad, where I can use if statement and check if it need to be done.

Comment: Why can't you set this label hidden in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:?

Comment: Vladimir, because if I set there IF statement, it reuse cells and result is wrong.

Comment: It is strange. Can I see you implementation?

Comment: if ([[myObject valueForKey:@"status"] isEqual:@"1"]) {
               cell.pushLabel.text = [tmpDict objectForKey:@"status"];
                            
                        }

Comment: It work, but when I scroll it reuse cell and pushLabel text appear in another's row's.

Comment: Yes, it will reuse a label state (text and other parameters) for new cells if you will not explicitly set them. In your example  you need just add else block with cell.pushLabel.text = @"".

Comment: Thank you Vladimir, you help me a lot! I can't set your answer as correct, because my question was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` method, `UITableView` still should have not been loaded so there no way you can get UITableViewCell objects.

One solution can be, `maintain` `flag` say you have

```
//Add in your .h file
BOOL hidePushLabel;
```

Now use these `flag` to `hide` `intially` in `tableview` like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSString *strCellIndentifier = @"cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCellIndentifier];

   if (cell)
   {
       //By default hidePushLabel will be NO so hide pushLabel
       if(!hidePushLabel)
          cell.pushLabel.hidden = YES;
       else
          cell.pushLabel.hidden = NO;
   }
   return cell;
}
```